# 'Explicit integral could not be found', integration including gamma function

Tags: matlab

I am getting a well-known error of "Explicit integral could not be found" if I try to evaluate following integral

```
 syms x

 funx = (cos(x)^(1/3))*cos(x);

 I=int(funx,x,0,pi/2);
```

I get the warning:

```
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found.
```

Mathematica evaluates this integral to 0.910744.

I have tried to use quadrature `quadgk`, `quadl`, but nothing works. Please help in identifying the fix for this problem. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much !

Comment: use integral() for numerical integration, not int()

Comment: Using Matlab 2012b, your code gave `I=pi^(3/2)/(4*gamma(2/3)*gamma(5/6))` and `double(I)` shows that this is indeed the same as Mathematica gave you. What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: I'm using the R2007b version of Matlab @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a newer version of Matlab (2012b), your code gave `I=pi^(3/2)/(4*gamma(2/3)*gamma(5/6))` and `double(I)=0.910743992957843`.

To do this numerically, you have to make `funx` an anonymous function, rather than a symbolic expression. There are two ways to do this.

Simply define `funx` as (without doing `syms x`)

```
funx = @(x) (cos(x)^(1/3))*cos(x);
```

or use `matlabFunction`,

```
syms x
funx = (cos(x)^(1/3))*cos(x);
funx = matlabFunction(funx);
```

Now you can use `integral`, `quad`, `quadgk`, etc. to do the integral numerically.

Answer (score 0):

Using `quad` in `octave` gives the correct result without warning:

```
octave:1> f = inline ("(cos(x)^(1/3))*cos(x)");
octave:2> quad(f,0,pi/2)
ans =  0.91074
```

But the `quad` function in `octave` is said to be more stable than its counterpart in `matlab`.

`octave` is the free open-source variant of `matlab`. It has an equivalent shell as well as most builtin commands but - according to my professor in *Numerical Integration*, better algorithms to perform integration.

Comment: I've never heard about this software. Thanks
The real problem I'm having is when I use
syms t X Y
u=X*cos(t)+Y*cos(3*t);
f=u^(1/3);
X=A+x1;
Y=-x1;
I=int(f*cos(t),t,0,pi/2)*4/pi;

where the variables X and Y are known.

Comment: I don follow, are `A`, `x1` and `y1` known as well? Do you call a function with these values set each time. Please edit your answer and be more specific about what you wish to achieve...